# Как поставить ударение: "крЕмень" или "кремЕнь"?

Tags: орфоэпия

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

КремЕнь.
Если бы не вы, никогда б не подмал, что в этом слове можно сделать ошибку. 
А вообще такие вещи проще и быстрее смотреть в словаре.

Comment: В который раз прошу отвечать на вопросы пользователей, не отсылая их в словари. Все можно посмотреть в словаре, тогда зачем нужен этот форум? Если люди спрашивают, неужели сложно ответить?
И, кстати, "Вы" здесь пишется с большой буквы.  
Администратор

Comment: Я пишу "вы" на форуме, посольку обращение не является официальным. так принято на многих известных мне форумах.
Могу и "Вы" писать, только зачем эта смешная чопорность? 

А вот насчет словарей... Я ставлю вопрос иначе.
_**Если на форуме, посвященном русскому языку запрещают отсылать в словари, то зачем нужен этот форум?**_
Простите, но это моя принципиальная позиция.

Comment: Ув.! Fuchoin Kazuki! В правилах форума сказано: не допускаются вопросы

 - ответ на которые сразу находится в словаре, например, "Как пишется слово "арбуз": орбуз или арбуз?"

Почему Вы убедительно призываете нас не соблюдать правила?

Comment: Может, список самых авторитетных словарей сразу включить в Справку?